# Python replace characters excluding whitespaces

Tags: python

I have changed the words into boxes where the whitespaces are still present but I am not sure how to make it so that when the player guesses a correct letter the boxes will turn into the letter.

heres how i changed it into boxes.

```
currentphrase = random.choice(WOFphrases)
hiddenphrase = re.sub('[A-Z]', u'\u2610',currentphrase)
```

I tried doing this but even the whitespaces get replaced with boxes.

```
for letter in currentphrase:
    if letter in completedletters:
        print(letter,end='')
    else:
        print(u'\u2610',end='')
```

Comment: Please read [mre] and provide your try as such. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex for this. Your second solution should work, just add a conditional for whitespaces

```
# Sample input
current_phrase = 'I am a phrase with letters and whitespaces'
completed_letters = ['a', 'e', 'w']  # make sure the letters here are already in lower case so it's easy to test later

# Solution
for letter in current_phrase:
    if letter.isspace() or letter.lower() in completed_letters:
        print(letter, end='')
    else:
        print(u'\u2610', end='')
```

Output:

```
☐ a☐ a ☐☐☐a☐e w☐☐☐ ☐e☐☐e☐☐ a☐☐ w☐☐☐e☐☐a☐e☐
```